# Month and Year Filters for post categories

Tags: php, wordpress

So I can create a filter that works for post archives by year, but I'm looking for something that will be category specific and will allow me to use either both a monthly and yearly (in one select menu or separate) select menu to filter categories of posts. I can't seem to find anything in the Wordpress API that does that, or a plugin. Is something straight forward and simple around to do this? Or do I have to code some sort of form submit that will alter the loop?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I solved it (kind of). I just made a custom categories template for the specific category and added a form with two select menus (one with months, one with years) and on submit, I'd validate and then add the year and monthnum values to the query_posts() parameter string. Seems to work well enough, but it's not ideal. I'd prefer to only display have months that actually have posts, and provide a count in the select menu.